# Placing a new value to a existing key in a hashtable

Tags: java

I am using a hashmap to populate a jtable.  The user selects a row(s) and clicks a edit button.  I am taking the value from the hashmap and placing it in a textarea.  The user can make changes and then clicks another button.  I have the new value and the key, but I am not sure how to write the changed value back to the right key in the hashmap.

THis is where I am writing the data out to the textarea

```
private void outputSelection() {
  StringBuffer csb = new StringBuffer();
  String s = "";
  int[] row = selectTable.getSelectedRows();

  for(int i = row.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
     String check = (String) EdiMapTableModel.getMapInstance().getValueAt(i, EdiMapTableModel.getMapInstance().COMMENT_COL); 
     if (!isNullOrEmpty(check)) {
        if (csb.length() > 0) {
            csb.append("\n");
        }
        csb.append(check);
     }
  }

  s = csb.toString();
  csb.setLength(0);
  output.append(s);
```

}

This is where I am trying to put the value back

```
private void inputSelection() {
  String s = output.getText();
  int[] row = selectTable.getSelectedRows();
  for(int i = row.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
     TCComponentItemRevision check = (TCComponentItemRevision) EdiMapTableModel.getMapInstance().getValueAt(i, EdiMapTableModel.getMapInstance().ITEMID_COL); 
     EdiMapTableModel.getMapInstance().commentBackMap(check, s);
     repaint();
  }
```

}

This is where I am trying to put it back in the map

```
public void commentBackMap(int row, TCComponentItemRevision id, String comment) {

   if(model.containsKey(id)) {
          model.put(id, comment);
   }           
   fireTableDataChanged();
}// end commentBackMap()
```

I know containsKey is not right above.  id is the key value

Do I need to iterate through the hashmap looking for a match?  Don't know if it matters but it is a linkedhashmap instead of a hashmap

Comment: So what you have isn't working?  `put(a,b);put(a,c);` Should overwrite b with c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the location of your map entry, you can't `put` it again since that's going to move it to the end of the `LinkedHashMap`. You'll need a holder object, say an `Object[1]`, where you'll replace its member without putting the map entry again.

Or maybe reevaluate your choice of `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`HashMap#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) documentation:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

So all you have to do is call `put` with the same key and the new value, it will do the replacement for you.

This also applies to `LinkedHashMap` because it inherits the `put` method from `HashMap`.

Comment: It may inherit `put`, but `HashMap.put` calls the overridden `addEntry`. How would insertion order semantics work if it didn't do that?